# I want different colours in my C# webform textbox!

Tags: webforms, textbox, colors

I want to format lines of text differently in a .net C# webforms text box, eg. some lines italic or different colour?  I know I can in windows forms, is there a richtextbox alternative for webforms? I find a lot of people asking but no answer...please can you help?

Comment: sorry - thanks for your answers but I was not specific enough - I want different lines to be formatted differently within the textbox, eg. line 1 red, line 2 green/bold etc.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the following properties

can set these inside your style tag

```
color: #ffffed
```

gives the text text inside a color

```
font-style: italic
```

will make the font in italics

```
<style>
   .styledText { color: #ffeded; font-style: italic; }
</style>
<input type="text" id="txt1" class="styledText" />
```

If you are using an asp.net textbox then you can use the cssclass property instead of the class property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want colours, italic and bold all on the one control - then you want a rich HTML edit control.  Have a look at [FCKeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) and [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)