# How to set the ForeColor of a string in a multiline TextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want different colours in my C# webform textbox!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254351/i-want-different-colours-in-my-c-webform-textbox)

I have a `TextBox` control with `TextMode="MultiLine"`. It is like a chat application where user name appear in different `color` and message appear in black color. How to change TextBox's `ForeColor` for user name only ?

Comment: You should use something differnt than textbox. Textbox cant show text in different colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repetitive question :

[I want different colours in my C# webform textbox!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254351/i-want-different-colours-in-my-c-webform-textbox)

you have two options :

- using custom editor with disabled toolbar! (as described in mentioned thread)
- using a editable div (typing allowed) and format elements in it using css!

another solution can be like this:

1. create a div element with a border witch will simulate your textbox
2. create a span element at first of your div to hold your username!
3. create a textbox at front of each username for its message to type!

but remember this solution is for new message for typing. for old messages you should use div and span only elements (without textbox) to show them. posted messages do not require textbox, because they are not editable!

Comment: can we put a scrollbar in `div` so that it is easy to see previous messages?

Comment: sure, just use overflow:auto in css properties of your div.

Comment: I try your solution but I mess up. Handling `div` and `span` from `CodeBehind` is hard.  Here chat application my mean is like yahoo Messenger or gmail chat. Have you any other solution or can you give some code example for above solution?

Comment: @Jams this was the only solution that I provided. If you are looking for a place to ask others to write your application it is not here.

Comment: In StackOverflow there are a huge Q&As in which users have provided example code for better explanation.  Your quote **`If you are looking for a place to ask others to write your application it is not here.`** Do you really think that I am looking someone to write my application ? I think you should regret for this line.  Any way in the meantime I have found other solutions also and your solution one of them, that’s Why I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this isn't possible (to change the colours of different parts of text in a textbox).  You can only have 1 colour, your best way would be to wrap it up in HTML displayed as you want with the user name as a separate div and the text control floated to it's right.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add different color to separate words in the textbox.
You can only set one color for the whole textbox.

> MyTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;

Any other scenario, you will have to build it using HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RichTextBox to get your appropriate result.

Comment: where it is `RichTextBox` in asp.net Visual Studio Toolbox?

Comment: @Jams Pls refer the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx

Comment: it is for `Windows Form` not `WebForm`